# Why won't my karma test work?

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner

I have this simple test:

```
    describe('My Controller', function() {

  beforeEach(function() {
    module('myApp');
    return inject(function($injector) {
      var $controller = $injector.get('$controller');
      this.rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
      this.scope = this.rootScope.$new();

      this.controller = $controller('MyCtrl', {
        '$scope': this.scope,
      });
    });
  });

  it('should have a controller', function() {
    expect(this.controller).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

the controller looks like this:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', '$filter', '$q', 'BookingService', 'ngToast', '$uibModal',
function($scope, $state, $filter, $q, BookingService, ngToast, $uibModal) {

  $scope.bs = BookingService;
  $scope.roundTrip = false;
  $scope.reservationDetails = {};
  $scope.originAddress = false;
  $scope.destinationAddress = false;
  $scope.reservationDetails.roundTrip = false;
  $scope.seatReservationDepart = {};
  $scope.charter = false;
}]);
```

The test keeps failing and the terminal is not really giving any useful information as to why.

Comment: You could go to http://localhost:9876/debug.html, this will let you debug in your console as you would normally which i prefer over terminal. As a guess to what goes wrong, your controller has a bunch of dependencies you don't provide in your tests.
— edit: try to add the error stack, because debugging without is very hard :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `this` in your test, it refers to different things in different parts of your suite.

Instead, initialize a scope "container" in the `describe` namespace:

```
describe('My Controller', function() {
  var scope = {};

  beforeEach(function() {
    module('myApp');

    return inject(function($injector) {
      var $controller = $injector.get('$controller');
      this.rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
      this.scope = this.rootScope.$new();

      scope.controller = $controller('MyCtrl', {
        '$scope': this.scope,
      });
    });
  });

  it('should have a controller', function() {
    expect(scope.controller).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```